# "Key Error" while trying to access the contents of a column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, keyerror

I am getting a "Key Error" while trying to access the  contents of a column in a Dataframe. Here, in this following code -

```
def scrape_topics_repos():
    print('Scraping list of topics')
    topics_df = scrape_topics()

    os.makedirs('data', exist_ok=True)
    for index, row in topics_df.iterrows():
        print('Scraping top repositories for "{}"'.format(row['Topic Name']))
        scrape_topic(row['Topic Link'], 'data/{}.csv'.format(row['Topic Name']))
```

The Error message is -

```
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Topic Name'
```

This is my entire code, please try running this, and help me with my error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
# Use the requests library to download the webpage on the local server
'''github_url = "https://github.com/topics"
r = requests.get(github_url)
response = r.text
if r.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception("Failed to load page {}".format(github_url))
doc1 = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')'''


def get_topic_titles(doc):
    topic_title_class = "f3 lh-condensed mb-0 mt-1 Link--primary"
    topic_title_tags = doc.find_all('p', {'class': topic_title_class})
    topic_titles = []
    for tag in topic_title_tags:
        topic_titles.append(tag.text)
    return topic_titles

# Extracting the description of the topic


def get_topic_description(doc):
    topic_description_class = "f5 color-fg-muted mb-0 mt-1"
    topic_description_tags = doc.find_all('p', {'class': topic_description_class})
    topic_descriptions = []
    for des in topic_description_tags:
        topic_descriptions.append(des.text.strip())
    return topic_descriptions


# Extracting the link to the topic
def get_topic_urls(doc):
    topic_link_class = "no-underline flex-1 d-flex flex-column"
    topic_link_tags = doc.find_all('a', {'class': topic_link_class})
    # topic_url = "https://github.com" + topic_link_tags[0]["href"]
    base_url = "https://github.com"
    topic_urls = []
    for url in topic_link_tags:
        topic_urls.append(base_url + url['href'])
    return topic_urls
# topic_urls = get_topic_urls(doc1)      # to iterate using index of the list


def scrape_topics():
    github_url = "https://github.com/topics"
    r = requests.get(github_url)
    response = r.text
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Failed to load page {}".format(github_url))
    doc1 = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    table_dict = {
        'Topic Title': get_topic_titles(doc1),
        'Topic Link': get_topic_urls(doc1),
        'Topic Description': get_topic_description(doc1)
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(table_dict)
# topic_df = scrape_topics()
# print(topic_df)                  #to check if topics are scraped properly


def get_topic_page(topic_url):
    r = requests.get(topic_url)
    response = r.text
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Failed to load page {}".format(topic_url))
    topic_doc = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    return topic_doc
# topic_doc = get_topic_page(topic_urls[0])


def get_repo_info(h3_tag, star_tag):
    a_tags = h3_tag.find_all('a')

    username = a_tags[0].text.strip()

    repo_name = a_tags[1].text.strip()
    base_url = "https://github.com"
    repo_url = base_url + a_tags[1]['href']

    star_count = star_tag.text.strip()
    return username, repo_name, repo_url, star_count


# FURTHER INFORMATION ABOUT TOPICS

def get_topic_repos(topic_doc):
    h3_selection_tag = 'f3 color-fg-muted text-normal lh-condensed'
    h3_tags = topic_doc.find_all('h3', {'class': h3_selection_tag})

    star_span_id = 'repo-stars-counter-star'
    star_tags = topic_doc.find_all('span', {'id': star_span_id})

    topic_repos_dict = {
        'username': [],
        'repo_name': [],
        'stars': [],
        'repo_url': []
    }

    for i in range(len(h3_tags)):
        repo_info = get_repo_info(h3_tags[i], star_tags[i])
        topic_repos_dict['username'].append(repo_info[0])
        topic_repos_dict['repo_name'].append(repo_info[1])
        topic_repos_dict['stars'].append(repo_info[2])
        topic_repos_dict['repo_url'].append(repo_info[3])

    return pd.DataFrame(topic_repos_dict)
# repo_df = get_topic_repos(get_topic_page(topic_urls[2]))   # to check if repo extraction is working fine
# print(repo_df)


def scrape_topic(topic_url, path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("The file {} already exists. Skipping...".format(path))
        return
    topic_df = get_topic_repos(get_topic_page(topic_url))
    topic_df.to_csv(path, index=False)


def scrape_topics_repos():
    print('Scraping list of topics')
    topics_df = scrape_topics()

    os.makedirs('data', exist_ok=True)
    for index, row in topics_df.iterrows():
        print('Scraping top repositories for "{}"'.format(row['Topic Name']))
        scrape_topic(row['Topic Link'], 'data/{}.csv'.format(row['Topic Name']))


scrape_topics_repos()
```

I printed out the dataframe to ensure that the df is actually being created, and it is, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Good approach, that a section of the code in question has already been referenced, but a recommendation for improvement - Take a few minutes to check:  How to create [mcve]. Try to focus on the essentials, this will also help you in perspective when debugging and often you will discover the error yourself in the process. Feel free to give it a try, . thank you

Comment: You should include a screenshot of or paste the error message [or at least mention *which* key the KeyError was raised on], as well as any outputs [such as the DataFrame you mentioned printing out]....Anyway, I [don't see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oLGO.png) any `'Topic Name'` in the DataFrame to be returned by `scrape_topics` - did you mean to access `['Topic Title']` instead?

Comment: thankyou so much, it was the mistake I made. Thankyou so much.

Comment: `print(topics_df.columns)` can help debug column index issues - it helps make sure the df is what you think it is.